# Strange C syntax in Lua library

Tags: c, lua, torch

I see functions like [this](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/lib/TH/generic/THTensor.c#L11) throughout the [torch library](https://github.com/torch/torch7)'s C code:

```
long THTensor_(storageOffset)(const THTensor *self)
{
  return self->storageOffset;
}
```

Is this a preprocessor thing, or something lua specific?  The idea, I think has something to do with the fact that `storageOffset` is a method of sorts on the `THTensor` "class", but I've never seen this kind of syntax.

Comment: `THTensor_` is [just a macro](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/fe9d4b46cb125fa1989d1515cea23e5d656a5087/lib/TH/THTensor.h#L8)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a preprocessor macro

```
lib/TH/THTensor.h:
#define THTensor_(NAME)   TH_CONCAT_4(TH,Real,Tensor_,NAME)
```

which leads to...

```
lib/TH/THGeneral.h.in:
#define TH_CONCAT_4(x,y,z,w) TH_CONCAT_4_EXPAND(x,y,z,w)
```

and finally...

```
lib/TH/THGeneral.h.in:
#define TH_CONCAT_4_EXPAND(x,y,z,w) x ## y ## z ## w
```

Therefore,

```
long THTensor_(storageOffset)(const THTensor *self)
```

ultimately becomes this:

```
long THRealTensor_storageOffset(const THTensor *self)
```

Aren't preprocessors just *grand* ?